# Curve modifier on an already curved model?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Hey there I have a brain neuron model which is already modeled in a curved shape.

[image]

then I create a Bezier Curve in the same shape and place the Origin to the start of the curve

[image]

and place the Origin at the same spot for the mesh I want to affect

[image]

but when I place a Curve Modifier on the mesh and choose the Bezier Curve it distorts the mesh like so...

[image]

but the weird thing is if I scale all the Bezier Curve points to 0 in the x-axis it fixes the mesh but then the curve isn't in the desired pose I want.

[image]

Can anyone help me with how I have a curved Bezier Curve affect a curved mesh?

Otherwise do I have to model the mesh in a straight line?

Answer (score 3):

As soon as your curve is not flat, it will deform the shape! The curve will deform the shape as much as the curve is itself deformed compared to a flat curve.

So, "do I have to model the mesh in a straight line", I would say yes.

Note that you need to put the origin of the curve at its beginning and make sure that its normals go in the good direction.

[image]

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Exactly.. The mesh doesn't 'know' it's curved.... but it's a question I've wanted to ask myself .. is there some way to 'apply' the deformation, so a controlling curve is aligned with the current state of the mesh?

Comment: I don't think so but there must be some way to find a simple solution when you need to do this kind of thing, perhaps you should ask the question with a practical case?

Comment: I think I've just found an answer, first test looks good ... negative shape keys ...  no time to write up / test exhaustively atm.. see if you get there first! :D

Comment: Oh yes ok, wow... maybe put the method here when you'll have time?

Comment: Nope, it wasn't there.. :( the inverse funcion is more complicated than that..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys,

I ended up following this tutorial

https://youtu.be/JS8V4_Ncn0w?fbclid=IwAR1C7Nu6KBUih5b4_dXfOOma701EUGuFvDQl_QDiOwVRDIHZmHtYIjRqpQI

just a shame there's no easy way to just use a curve on a curved mesh